# Removing phrases with custom stop words from a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
listA = ['New Delhi', 'Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France', 'To Washington']
stopwordlist = ['new', 'To']
```

I am trying to get something like this

```
finalList = ['Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France']
```

What I have tried until now works if I am looking for whole words:

```
listB = []
for item in listA:
    if item not in stopwordlist:
        listB.append(item)
    else:
        continue
....            
....
    return listB
```

We may split the `item` then check those in the stopwordlist. But this seems like to many workarounds. Or I could use a regex `re.match`.

Comment: So you have the list of all the words that need to eliminate !

Comment: I am looking for something if a substring (a stopword) matches, then remove that word also from the initial list.

Comment: Should it be removed only if it starts with the string or if it contains it? e.g. If the stop word were `To` would you remove `Washington To`? Or if `To` formed part of a word e.g. `Sacremento`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this,

```
>>> listA = ['New Delhi', 'Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France', 'To Washington']
>>> stopwordlist = ['new', 'To']
>>> finalList = [i for i in listA if not any(j.lower() in i.lower() for j in stopwordlist)]
>>> finalList
['Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France']
```

or You could use the builtin `filter` function.

```
>>> listA = ['New Delhi', 'Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France', 'To Washington']
>>> stopwordlist = ['new', 'To']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not any(j.lower() in x.lower() for j in stopwordlist), listA))
['Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France']
```

Comment: @Betafish what about this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
sl = tuple(i.lower() for i in stopwordlist)
[i for i in listA if not i.lower().startswith(sl)]
```

Output

```
['Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France']
```

Comment: Q: Why are you using a list comprehension to turn it into a tuple? Use a generator and save memory. TLDR: The `[` and `]` in the first line are a waste of memory.

Comment: @Adirio for the sake of using built-in function `starstwith`.

Comment: I mean avoid turning it into a list before turning it into a tuple. Remove the `[` and `]` and it will be a generator creating the tuple instead of a generator creating the list that creates the tuple. Did I make myself clear this time?

Answer (score 1):

```
listA =['New Delhi','Moscow', 'Berlin','France', 'To Washington']
stopwordlist = ['new','To']
listA = [i.lower() for i in listA]
stopwordlist = [i.lower() for i in stopwordlist]

listB =[]

for item in listA:
    flag = True
    for i in item.split(' '):
        if i in stopwordlist:
            flag =False
    if flag:
        listB.append(item)
print(listB)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to lower your stop words also the words against you run you stopwords:

```
listA = ['New Delhi', 'Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France', 'To Washington']
stopwordlist = ['new', 'To']

stop_words = {e.lower() for e in stopwordlist}
finalList = [e for e in listA if not stop_words.intersection(e.lower().split())]
```

or you can use regex:

```
import regex as re

stop_words_regex = re.compile(r"\L<words>", words=stop_words)
finalList = [e for  e in listA if not stop_words_regex.findall(e.lower())]
```

Output:

```
['Moscow', 'Berlin', 'France']
```